# Java: How to solve a large factorial using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, int, factorial

All the solutions online I can find use `BigInteger` but I have to solve this using arrays.

I'm only a beginner and I even took this to my Computer Science club and even couldn't figure it out.

Every time I enter a number greater than `31`, the output is always zero.

Also, when I enter a number greater than `12`, the output is always incorrect.

E.g. `fact(13)` returns `1932053504` when it should return `6227020800`

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Fact
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number you wish to factorial");
        int x = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println(fact(x));
    }

    public static int fact(int x)
    {
        int[] a = new int[x];

        int product = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = x;
            x--;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            product = product * a[i];
        }

        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "Bigger number" is 20 a big number, is  50 a big number is 1000 a big number?

Comment: firstly you don't need an array, your first loop in fact() is redundant; secondly, what is your higher number? int in Java has a upper limit, factorial can easily go beyond that limit

Comment: I did a few runs of it I found the following: the largest number that it calculates "correctly" is `31` with a value of `738197504` and then it does not return zero on `32` but rather `-2147483648`. Any number greater than `32` then returns `0`

Comment: I suggest you look at the implementation of bigInt if you want to learn more. the problem comes when u multiply product * a[i]; there is a limit to how big a result u can store back into an int - it will overflow and the rest of your calculations will be wrong.

Comment: You basically need to implement the digit-by-digit addition and long multiplication algorithms. Recall back to elementary school, and implement these in code.

Comment: If you have to use arrays, it's probably the case that you need to store the digits of the big number in the array, and you should do as @Nayuki Minase has mentioned and implement the long multiplication algorithm using arrays.

Comment: Use     'long  product = 1' or  'double product = 1' and refer limits https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum Values Make Large Numbers Terrible

Sadly, because of the [maximum values of integers and longs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), you are unable to go any larger than

For Longs:

```
2^63 - 1

9223372036854775807

9 quintillion 223 quadrillion 372 trillion 36 billion 854 million 775 thousand 807
```

and For Ints:

```
2^31 - 1

2147483647

2 billion 147 million 483 thousand 647
```

(I put the written names in to show the size)

At any point in time during the calculation you go over these, "maximum values,"  you will overflow the variable causing it to behave differently than you would expect, sometimes causing weird zeros to form.

Even `BigInteger`s  have problems with this although it can go up to numbers way higher than just `longs` and `ints` which is why they is used with methods that generate massive numbers like factorials.

You seem to want to avoid using `BigInteger` and only use primatives so `long` will be the largest data type that you can use.

Even if you convert everything over to `long` (except the array iterators of course), you will only be able to calculate the factorial up to 20 accurately. Anything over that would overflow the variable. This is because 21! goes over the "maximum value" for longs.

In short, you would need to either use `BigInteger` or create your own class to calculate the factorials for numbers greater than 20.